Displaying specific field values of attribute table in QGIS Print Layout
I am building a layout where I want to add the attribute table of the map and only display the maximum and minimum values of a field. I think there is the option to filter by expression but I am not sure how to set it.
The location is where it says "filtra amb" which means "filter by"


So, you read the tooltips to the minimum() and maximum() expression?

Yes, I've found it now. Thanks

Please put it as a valid answer, @Erik :)
